# Understanding conda conflict resolution message

Tags: conda

I have been trying to resolve some conflicts in `conda` and trying to understand the conflict messages.

My environment.yml file is as follows

```
name: main_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pandas==0.19.2
  - numpy==1.12.1
  - scipy==0.18.1
  - jinja2==2.8
  - markupsafe==0.23
  - pillow==4.0.0
  - luigi==2.8.0
  - psycopg2==2.6.2
  - pymysql==0.7.11
  - requests==2.22.0
  - elasticsearch==6.3.1
  - gspread==0.6.2
  - oauth2client==4.0.0
  - s3fs==0.2.0
  - pytz
  - bs4
  - html5lib
  - mysqlclient
  - matplotlib
  - paramiko
  - pip
  - pyyaml
  - pygithub
  - runipy
  - seaborn
  - xlwt
  - pip:
      - pycountry==17.1.8
      - geolib==1.0.6
      - sqlalchemy==1.0.4
      - pyathena==1.3.0
      - pyspark==2.1.3
      - flask==0.12.3
      - shapely==1.6.4.post1
      - aws-kinesis-agg==1.1.0
      - sendgrid==2.2.1
      - google-api-python-client==1.6.1
      - boto==2.45.0
      - googleads
```

I see conflict messages like this

```
Package matplotlib conflicts for:
seaborn -> matplotlib[version='>=1.4.3|>=2.1.2']
matplotlib

Package jinja2 conflicts for:
jinja2==2.8
runipy -> jinja2[version='>=2.7.2']
runipy -> nbconvert[version='>=4.0.0'] -> jinja2[version='>=2.4']

Package enum34 conflicts for:
paramiko -> cryptography[version='>=2.5'] -> enum34
luigi==2.8.0 -> enum34

...
```

I am trying to understand how these are even conflicts. Let's take `jinja2` conflict. According to my understanding 2.8 should be able to satisfy the requirement. So why is that reported as a conflict?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to print every possible package that has at least two constraints inheriting from the specifications. It doesn’t actually limit it to the ones that have conflicts, but presumably they are included somewhere in what is printed out.

Comment: Can you share the full conflict output? Where do these package versions come from? While it might not resolve the issue, could you loosen some of the version restrictions?

Comment: To anyone coming in later to face the same issue, I went through each of the dependency conflict messages and found that there was one conflict which was an actual conflict. Resolved that all errors went away. `conda` seems to be giving bad conflict messages